# Introduction to algebraic geometry

Tags: book-recommendation

I want to start learning algebraic geometry. What introductory books do you recommend? My background in algebra includes group and basic ring theory, as well as some module theory. Do I need Galois theory?

Thanks!

Comment: I would do some commutative algebra first.